# How can I merge typescript interfaces over multiple files in the same namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations, typescript-namespace

I am trying to refactor an unwieldy config interface/object by separating its various sections into separate files under a `namespace` I've cleverly named `Config`.

The documentation talks about [namespaces that span multiple files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files) and [declaration merging of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), but I can't seem to get them to work together.

**src/config/index.ts**

```ts
/// <reference path="./server.ts" />
import fs from 'fs';
import json5 from 'json5';

const _config = readConfig();

namespace Config {
    export const config = _config;

    export interface IConfig {
        someGeneralProperty: {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

function readConfig(): Config.IConfig {
    return json5.parse(fs.readFileSync('./path/to/config.json', 'utf-8'));
}

function doSomeOtherStuff() {
    // fails: Property 'server' does not exist on type 'IConfig'.
    console.log(_config.server.host);
}
```

**src/config/server.ts**

```ts
/// <reference path="./index.ts" />

namespace Config {
    export interface IConfig {
        server: {
            host: string;
            port: number;
        }
    }
}
```

**src/index.ts**

```ts
// fails: Module '"./config"' has no exported member 'config'.
import { config } from './config'; 

// fails: Cannot use namespace 'Config' as a value.
// fails: Namespace 'Config' has no exported member 'config'.
import config = Config.config;
```

I've tried several variations of exporting things, such as `export default Config;`, `export namespace Config {...}` in each of the `src/config/...` files, changing `export const config` to `export var config`.  In `src/config/index.ts` I tried `export * from './server'`.  Nothing seems to help.

I have a feeling I'm just going about this all wrong.

Oddly, the interfaces within the namespace in every file are exported from the namespace, so in `src/index.ts`, I can do:

```
import IConfig = Config.IConfig;

let c: IConfig;
console.log(c.server.host);
```

but I cannot do that in either `src/config/index.ts` nor `src/config/server.ts`.

Comment: In docs of typescript they just use reference tag like:
`/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />`
and then they use the namespace
`let validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};`

There is no import mentioned. I think you should use it same way, do the reference `/// <reference path="./index.ts" />` instead of import and then you should be able to use `Config.config`

I didnt test it so I do not post it as an answer. But might be worth trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first you should decide yourself, if you want to assign the `config` object to a module scope (i.e. `import`/`export`) or in the global scope (i.e.`window` in browsers, `global` in node).

The main purpose of namespaces is to define properties/values on the global scope. As you pointed out correctly with the links, equally named namespaces are merged - that includes contained inner members like the `IConfig` interface.

Here is the deal: Merging only happens when the file containing the `namespace` is a script (a non-module file without `import`/`export` at top-level).

In `src/config/index.ts`, you've got `import` statements, so the file becomes a module and `namespace Config` does not get merged. Instead it is rather a module internal namespace, which is not even `export`ed (see [Needless Namespacing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing), [Do not use namespaces in modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#do-not-use-namespaces-in-modules) in the docs). The `Config` namespace in `src/config/server.ts` forms its own global namespace (non-module file), that is why you can still use the contained `IConfig`  type.

In summary, if you want to have the config (value and type) globally, make sure, every part of the multi file part namespace is declare in a non-module file. If the config is to be exported from a module (preferred way if feasible!; better encapsulation, no global scope pollution, the "modern" way), read on.

#### Alternative: export config in a module

src/config/server.ts:

```
export interface ServerConfig {
  server: {
    host: string;
    port: number;
  }
}

// you could also read a server-specific config value here, export it
// and merge it with a separately read common config value in index.ts
// export serverConfig: ServerConfig = readServerConfig()
```

src/config/index.ts:

```
import { ServerConfig } from "./server"

interface CommonConfig {
  someGeneralProperty: {
    // ...
  }
}

export type IConfig = CommonConfig & ServerConfig

export const config: IConfig = readConfig(); // whatever readConfig looks like
```

src/index.ts:

```
import { config } from './config'; 

config.server;
config.someGeneralProperty
```

Feel free to adjust the parts, you need.